# How do i put an array in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

How do i put an session array into mysql rows?

Session array output when using `print_r($_SESSION['producten'])`:

```
Array
(
    [producten] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [aantal] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [aantal] => 1
                )

        )
)
```

Mysql:

```
$order_ins = "INSERT INTO orders_products (order_id,product_id,product_amount) VALUES
('".$_SESSION['order_id']."', '".$_SESSION['product_id']."','".$_SESSION['aantal']."' )";

mysql_query($order_ins) or die("Ehh..error!?" . mysql_error());
```

What I want is that the "product_id" and "aantal" (means amount in dutch) will be inserted in mysql rows. Afterwards the products and amounts can be filtered using the "order_id"

Comment: Give each field its own column. That what databases are designed to work.

Comment: Session data (can be edited outside of your script) + string concatenation SQL query building = risk of SQL injection.

Comment: That's a very simple problem to solve. Use foreach to create the sql

Comment: `foreach ($_SESSION['producten'] as $product) {`. Inside `foreach` use `$product['order_id']`, `$product['product_id']` and `$product['aantal']` in you query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, however, be aware of the risk of SQL injection.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders_products (order_id, product_id, product_amount) VALUES ";

$i = 1;

foreach($_SESSION[producten] as $innerArray) {
    $sql .= '(' . $_SESSION[order_id] . ', ' . $innerArray[product_id] . ', ' . $innerArray[aantal] . ')';

    if($i < count($_SESSION[producten])) $sql .= ', ';

    $i++;
}

mysql_query($sql) or die("Ehh..error!?" . mysql_error());
```

**Result**

The value of `$sql` would be:

```
INSERT INTO orders_products (order_id, product_id, product_amount) VALUES (#, 3, 2), (#, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Got any tips to remove the SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: @jediah use prepared statements like the ones in my answer and Bill's.

Comment: @jediah You can use `mysqli_prepare`. Read up on `mysqli_` functions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1679).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to store session information in a database. I wrote a class that does this.

See here:

[sessionwrapper.php](http://pastebin.com/8rTmf3f2)

I use a small wrapper around PDO:

[databasehelper.php](http://pastebin.com/cdRWb2cH)

It's very easy to use:

Instead of:

```
session_start();
```

Do:

```
require_once("sessionwrapper.php");

SessionWrapper::startGlobalSession();
```

The DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_session (
    session_id VARCHAR(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    last_request_time INTEGER,
    session_data TEXT
);
```

It automatically keeps track of your session information in the PDO database connection that you provide. You don't need to do anything different. Just set your `$_SESSION` variable as normal.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    echo "You are already logged in. <br />\n";
}
else
{
    printLoginForm();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful for future projects! Will give credits in the script for using it. Do you have a site or email i can put in the credits?

Comment: @jediah I'd rather not put my email on the public web. You can just use my name if you'd like. It isn't a very common name.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier with PDO and parameterized statements.  No risk of SQL injection, no confusing string concatenation, and no worry about whether you escaped your quote characters correctly.

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders_products (order_id, product_id, product_amount)
        VALUES (:order_id, :product_id, :product_amount)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$data = array("order_id" => $_SESSION["order_id"]);
foreach ((array) $_SESSION["producten"] as $order) {
    $data["product_id"]     = $order["product_id"];
    $data["product_amount"] = $order["aantal"];
    $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful to learn from. It's always good to learn new methods

Answer (score 0):

You can store the array if you serialize it first. That way it wil be a string you can save.

For searching and statistics it could make sense to store each product in the cart on its own row in the table. But be careful to choose the unique id column in the table (if you have one). For instance, Can the cart have the same product twice in the cart (the same t-shirt, one in red and one in green).